How can I use an identifier from one dataframe to look in another dataframe for preceding results under the same identifier (using R?
I have a dataframe (sample) of hospital admission details with microbiology results. Each row includes a hospital ID (hid) for the patient, a spell ID for the admission (SpellID) and a specimen ID (specID) for the microbiology result, as well as admission (AdmDateTime) and discharge dates (DisDateTime) for the spell and the date of microbiology specimen collection (dc).
I want to look into another dataframe (wmward_long) to see if there are any OTHER admissions for the same patient in the preceding 90 days to the date of specimen collection (irrespective of if these admissions are associated with a microbiology test result).
If there are, I want to add a new column (Adm_Prior_90d) to the sample dataframe which gives a TRUE/FALSE result.
I tried to generate a function to do this and then to apply this to each row, however it seems  operate extremely slowly and then freeze.
sample <- data.frame(
"hid" = c("a123; B456; c567; d890"),
"SpellID" = c(12783, 54462, 92369, 73682), 
"AdmDateTime" = c("2021-04-04 06:17:00","2021-04-04 06:20:00","2021-04-04 06:33:00", "2021-04-04 06:56:00"),
"DisDateTime" = c("2021-04-14 06:17:00","2021-04-24 06:20:00","2021-05-05 06:33:00", "2022-04-04 06:56:00"),
"SpecID" = c("c1893", "c6790", "c8370", "c7908"), 
"dc" = c("2021-04-05 06:17:00","2021-04-06 06:20:00","2021-04-05 06:33:00", "2021-04-06 06:56:00"))

wmward_long <- data.frame(
"hid" = c("a123; B456; c567; d890; a123; B456"),
"SpellID" = c(12783, 54462, 92369, 73682, 89097, 54444), 
"AdmDateTime" = c("2021-04-04 06:17:00","2021-04-04 06:20:00","2021-04-04 06:33:00", "2021-04-04 06:56:00", "2021-03-04 06:17:00","2021-02-04 06:20:00"),
"DisDateTime" = c("2021-04-14 06:17:00","2021-04-24 06:20:00","2021-05-05 06:33:00", "2022-04-04 06:56:00", "2021-03-20 06:17:00","2021-02-27 06:20:00"))

adm_prior_90d <- function(culture_date, hospital_ID, spell_ID) {
recent_admissions <- filter(wmward_long,
hid == hospital_ID &
SpellID != spell_ID &
DisDateTime < culture_date & DisDateTime >= culture_date - 90)
return(nrow(recent_admissions) > 0)
}

sample <- sample %>%
mutate(AdmPrior90d = mapply(adm_prior_90d, dc, hid, SpellID))

Is there a better way of doing this?

Can you confirm you are representing the hid variable correctly? You have entered a single long hid for each table, that is copied to all rows, instead of a vector with different elements for each row. I think you meant "hid" = c("a123", "B456", "c567", "d890"), and c("a123", "B456", "c567", "d890", "a123", "B456"),

You are correct! My apologies

Once you convert your datetimes to datetime format (e.g. with lubridate::ymd_hms) and create a variable representing the "90 days prior"...
sample2 <- sample |>
  mutate(AdmDateTime = lubridate::ymd_hms(AdmDateTime),
         AdmDateTime_prior90 = AdmDateTime - lubridate::days(90))
  
wmward_long2 <- wmward_long |>
  mutate(across(contains("DateTime"), lubridate::ymd_hms))
  

...you can use left_join(X,Y, join_by(overlaps(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max))) to find all the overlapping periods.
overlaps <- sample2 |>
  left_join(wmward_long2, 
            join_by(hid, 
                    overlaps(AdmDateTime_prior90, AdmDateTime, 
                             AdmDateTime, DisDateTime))) |>
  filter(SpellID.x != SpellID.y)

sample2 |>
  left_join(overlaps |> distinct(hid) |> mutate(Adm_Prior_90 = TRUE)) |>
  replace_na(list(Adm_Prior_90 = FALSE))

Result
  hid SpellID         AdmDateTime         DisDateTime SpecID                  dc AdmDateTime_prior90 Adm_Prior_90
1 a123   12783 2021-04-04 06:17:00 2021-04-14 06:17:00  c1893 2021-04-05 06:17:00 2021-01-04 06:17:00         TRUE
2 B456   54462 2021-04-04 06:20:00 2021-04-24 06:20:00  c6790 2021-04-06 06:20:00 2021-01-04 06:20:00         TRUE
3 c567   92369 2021-04-04 06:33:00 2021-05-05 06:33:00  c8370 2021-04-05 06:33:00 2021-01-04 06:33:00        FALSE
4 d890   73682 2021-04-04 06:56:00 2022-04-04 06:56:00  c7908 2021-04-06 06:56:00 2021-01-04 06:56:00        FALSE


Note: I presume you intended the example data to be:  (note different hid data)
sample <- data.frame(
  "hid" = c("a123", "B456", "c567", "d890"),
  "SpellID" = c(12783, 54462, 92369, 73682), 
  "AdmDateTime" = c("2021-04-04 06:17:00","2021-04-04 06:20:00","2021-04-04 06:33:00", "2021-04-04 06:56:00"),
  "DisDateTime" = c("2021-04-14 06:17:00","2021-04-24 06:20:00","2021-05-05 06:33:00", "2022-04-04 06:56:00"),
  "SpecID" = c("c1893", "c6790", "c8370", "c7908"), 
  "dc" = c("2021-04-05 06:17:00","2021-04-06 06:20:00","2021-04-05 06:33:00", "2021-04-06 06:56:00"))
wmward_long <- data.frame(
  "hid" = c("a123", "B456", "c567", "d890", "a123", "B456"),
  "SpellID" = c(12783, 54462, 92369, 73682, 89097, 54444), 
  "AdmDateTime" = c("2021-04-04 06:17:00","2021-04-04 06:20:00","2021-04-04 06:33:00", "2021-04-04 06:56:00", "2021-03-04 06:17:00","2021-02-04 06:20:00"),
  "DisDateTime" = c("2021-04-14 06:17:00","2021-04-24 06:20:00","2021-05-05 06:33:00", "2022-04-04 06:56:00", "2021-03-20 06:17:00","2021-02-27 06:20:00"))

